# How do I make sliding pictures in HTML?

Tags: jquery, html

How do I make sliding picture animations? For example, the one on https://www.godaddy.com/
I don't need the exact code, just a link to a webpage or just an explanation on how to do it. I've already searched stackoverflow for this question, but I couldn't find anything so please excuse me if this is a repeat question.

Comment: see this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) on w3schools

Comment: here the simple css slider https://codepen.io/cybrox/pen/cyiJI

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a plug and play solution, try lightslider.js http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/. I've used it in a few projects and it's easy to use and customizable.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking out the bootstrap carousel here:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Answer (score 0):

Slick is the last carouse you will ever need. It says so right on the page!

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/